# VS Code: Commands run through Command Palette (CMD+Shift+P) won't show in Output

Tags: vs-code, sfdx-plugin

I could be mistaken here, but earlier when I used to use VS Code and the SFDX CLI plugins through the Command Palette (i.e. Command + Shift + P) to kick off a process (deploying code, retrieving code etc.), the output window (or maybe terminal) would show the corresponding CLI command. This was very helpful in learning the actual commands themselves, and a time-saver when I needed to re-run the commands via terminal with a small modification (such as running specific tests during deploying). But the last few months, I'm not seeing the corresponding commands in either Output or Terminal when I execute it via Cmd Palette. Did some setting change somewhere, or am I imagining it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see the Commands used in the execution as per instructions documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/vscode-commands)

> To see the output of the commands that you run, select View > Output, and then select Salesforce CLI from the dropdown menu. Alternatively, click Show in the completion notification.

Also make sure `show-salesforce-cli-msg` flag is set in the extension settings

You will find  the Salesforce Feature Previews Settings like above in  the [VSCode Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

[image]

Finally for some commands, Salesforce CLI commands are not executed and instead the Salesforce VSCode Extension uses Salesforce API like tooling. For these commands you wont see SFDX Commands.

One Such Example is `Retrieve Source` and `Deploy source` no more uses CLI SFDX Commands for Non scratch org.

Comment: Thanks for your input!
I did confirm that that flag is set, but I still don't see the commands in the output. For instance, if I retrieve a specific class from the org, all the output I get is:
 (in following comment)

Comment: 17:56:18.772 Starting SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org

=== Retrieved Source
FULL NAME                     TYPE       PROJECT PATH                                                            
────────────────────────────  ─────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
ChangePasswordControllerTest  ApexClass  force-app/main/default/classes/ChangePasswordControllerTest.cls         
ChangePasswordControllerTest  ApexClass  force-app/main/default/classes/ChangePasswordControllerTest.cls-meta.xml

17:56:20.278 ended SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org

Comment: Retrieve Source and Deploy source no more uses CLI SFDX Commands for Non scratch org. Hope that helps

Comment: Ahhh ok, that answers it! Thank you! So no way to get to know the command used while deploying/retrieving, except forming it on one's own using documentation?